# regexp javascript simplify

Tags: javascript, regex

`^(all|contact|all,contact|contact,all)$`

do not allow `all,all` or `contact,contact` or `all,contact,all`, etc.

I need to be able to have an equivalent pattern, but I want to reduce because I may have more elements in the future and finding all possible combinations would be difficult.

eg with 3 elements
`^(all|contact|another|all,contact|contact,all|all,another|another,all|all,another,contact|all,contact,another|contact,all,another|contact,another,all|another,all,contact|another,contact,all)$`

It should accept one word or multiple words separated by commas and each word only appears once. Thanks for the help in advanced.

Comment: Something like [`^(?!.*\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b)(?:another|contact|all)(?:,(?:another|contact|all))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/d1vdwB/1) might do.

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that worked thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
 /^(?!.*\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b)(?:another|contact|all)(?:,(?:another|contact|all))*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d1vdwB/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?!.*\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if,
  immediately after any 0+ chars other than line break chars there is a whole word that also occurs after another chunk of any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `(?:another|contact|all)` - one of the three alternatives
- `(?:,(?:another|contact|all))*` - any 0+ repetitions of:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `(?:another|contact|all)` - one of the three alternatives
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

A bit un-regexlike, but would it not be easier and possibly more performant to just `split()` on the `,` character and check for uniqueness on the resulting array?

This would arguably be more robust and easier to maintain, especially if you have a heavily minimised/difficult to read regular expression to begin with and wanted to add more words.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't answer the question.